# In what conditions the checkError() method of the PrintStream object returns true?

Tags: java, io, printstream

As given in JAVA docs, the variable 'trouble' gets set to true whenever there is a java.io.IOException. I write a program:

```
import java.io.*;
class First
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                File f = new File("a.txt");
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(f);
                f.delete();
                ps.write(65);
                boolean b = ps.checkError();
                System.out.println(b); //Output: false
                ps.close();
        }
}
```

Even if I deleted the file before writing, why the method checkError() is not returning true? Please give an example when the variable 'trouble' set to true and the method checkError() returns true.

Comment: What is `MyPrintStream`?

Comment: Deleting a file and then writing to it is simple stuff for any program. Try deleting a file and then reading from it :-)

Comment: what is `MyPrintStream`

Answer (score 1):

According to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#checkError()):

> **`checkError`** returns `true` if and only if this stream has encountered an `IOException` other than `InterruptedIOException`, or the [`setError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#setError()) method has been invoked.

Comment: He thinks he's caused an `IOException` by deleting the file. He hasn't, but that's what he thinks.

Answer (score -2):

> Even if I deleted the file before writing, why the method checkError() is not returning true? Please give an example when the variable 'trouble' set to true and the method checkError() returns true.

1. You don't know that you deleted the file, as you aren't checking the result of `File.delete()`.
2. You are creating the `PrintStream` without `autoFlush`, so `println()` does nothing to the file system.
3. There is no reason why deleting the file should cause an `IOException` on write even if it succeeds and the write is flushed. Try it with `FileOutputStream` for example.

Your question is founded on three false assumptions.

Comment: 1. The file is getting deleted, I used Thread.sleep(5000) to see it in GUI. 2. I used autoFlush as true and passed newLine too, result is same. 3. Third point is correct. I used DataOutputStream and this also does not throw an exception. Now my doubt is how trying to write on deleted file does not cause any exception?

Comment: @mynameisGYAN So that leaves you with two flawed assumptions.